# How to import from config file in Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have followed the layout of my Flask project from http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world.

I have the following structure:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    forms.py
    myFile.py
run.py
config.py
```

In views.py, forms.py I am able to use

```
from config import basedir
```

However I cannot use that in myFile.py

I added

```
import Flask
```

and when I modify it, the Flask web server restarts, but it doesn't say found changes in app/myFile.py restarting it just restarts.

What do I need to do to be able to use

```
from config import basedir
```

in my python file. I don't see anything special being done in `__init__.py` for forms.py.

EDIT: This is my `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import basedir

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
from app import views
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

When people talk about configs in Flask, they are generally talking about loading values into the app's configuration.  In your above example you could have something like `app.config.from_object('config')` in your `init.py` file.  Then all the configuration values will be loaded into the `app.config` dictionary.

Then in any of your files you could just import the app object to gain access to that dictionary.  I tend to access that `app` object by doing `from flask import current_app as app` then just `app.config['MY_SETTING']` to get the value I care about. [Read up more in the documenation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/).

Comment: I have app.config.from_object('config') in my __init__.py file. Do you know why "from config import basedir" works in views.py and forms.py?

Comment: Thanks man. In the doc. it was not explained how to access the config settings from other files.

Answer (score 34):

After a little bit of fiddling (and a little help from the 'net), I could improve this further, by changing the code to include the config to:

```
app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
```

This enables this cool pattern for configurations:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'do-i-really-need-this'
    FLASK_HTPASSWD_PATH = '/secret/.htpasswd'
    FLASK_SECRET = SECRET_KEY
    DB_HOST = 'database' # a docker link

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = False
    DEBUG = False
    DB_HOST = 'my.production.database' # not a docker link
```

What's left now is to see how to integrate testing configs into this, but at least it feels less clumsy.

Comment: How does the `app.config.from_object ` become aware of the config module ? I have `config` module along with `__init__.py` module. I keep getting this error: `ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config.ProductionConfig'`

Comment: I see the same error. My installable app code lies in `app/src/myapp/` where also my `__init__.py` resides. Thus `INSTANCE_PATH` is `app/src/instance/`. Could you fix this @Ciastopiekarz?

Comment: Here should `app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')` instead be `app.config.from_object(config.ProductionConfig)` where `config` is an instance of the `Config` class?

Comment: @greg No, `from_object` takes a string which is then used to dynamically import the module. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#development-production. Yes, it's poorly named and very confusing. Also using strings to reference modules is not the best idea - reduces ability of IDE to trace usages.

Comment: This is the whole problem with newer languages that have forgotten about good design; this is not cool. Is that code or configuration? Code and configuration should be separate. https://12factor.net/

Comment: You should not load code as a configuration. The whole code is executed to initiate the classes.

Answer (score 4):

I created a config.json file in my flask project - root folder, like below:

> config.json

```
{
    "mail_settings":{
        "MAIL_SERVER": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "MAIL_PORT": 465,
        "MAIL_USE_TLS": "False",
        "MAIL_USE_SSL": "True",
        "MAIL_USERNAME": "your_mail@gmail.com",
        "MAIL_PASSWORD": "your_password"
    },
    "database":{
        "MYSQL_HOST":"localhost",
        "MYSQL_USER": "user_name",
        "MYSQL_PASSWORD":"password",
        "MYSQL_DB":"database_name"
    }
}
```

and just add below code in where we want to access configuration values. for example, i am going to use in app.py like below:

first import flask json library:

```
import json
```

second open the file to read and store the json in some variable like below:

```
with open('config.json') as config_file:
    config_data = json.load(config_file)
```

add below code after creates a Flask application, named app `app = Flask(__name__)` like below, for access the config.json - configuration values.

```
# mail configuration
mail_settings = config_data['mail_settings']
app.config.update(mail_settings)

# database configuration
db_settings = config_data['database']
app.config.update(db_settings)
```

Comment: Before downvoting, my request is we have to explain the wrong part.
@Siva, In Flask app, we can create a config.py file in the root folder for configurations. OP & every one discussing about that config.py file. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuration-best-practices

Comment: Sorry, when I started to create the config file I didn't check the documents properly, whichever I used in my project for configuration, @SarathlalN Tnx to you, I can understand my mistake now.