# 'flask run' or 'python run' which to use?

Tags: python, flask

Reading http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/ describes using 'flask run' to start flask based app.

I've been using `python run.py myconfig.conf` as there does not appear to be an option to set config file 'myconfig.conf' as part of flask startup.

my run code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config.from_pyfile(sys.argv[1]))

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=app.config["PORT"])
```

Can see myconfig.conf is registered with `sys.argv[1]`
Should I use flask mechanism instead of python for executing flask server ? If so how to pass myconfig.conf to main method ?

As using :

```
flask run myconfig.py
```

returns error :

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (myconfig.py)
```

Comment: You are not supposed to pass the config file as an argument to the script. Try an environmental variable instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122312/how-to-import-from-config-file-in-flask..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To run the application you can either use the flask command or python’s -m switch with Flask. Before you can do that you need to tell your terminal the application to work with by exporting the FLASK_APP environment variable:
>
> $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
>
> $ flask run
>
> - Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

from the above link itself. you have to set FLASK_APP environmet variable to your script

Comment: so instead of settings config in 'app.config.from_pyfile(sys.argv[1]))' from main it's set somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use flasks custom commands (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#custom-commands) which will help you to define your own flask command line options. There you can set app.config.from_pyfile(confige_file). Then run flask run to execute flask server.

```
    @app.cli.command()
    @click.argument('config_file')
    def set_config(config_file):
        app.config.from_pyfile(confige_file)
```