# `python -m app` fails to open serial port but `flask run` works

Tags: python, flask, windows-10, pyserial

I've written a microserver in Flask that monitors a serial port.  When I launch flask via

```
> flask run
```

it launches the server, which in turn opens the serial port.  But I'd prefer to use the `python -m app` version so I can add command line arguments, i.e.:

```
> py -m app [my arguments]
```

This approach launches the server but fails to open the serial port:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM15': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

Can someone explain the difference?

P.S.: This is Windows 10, Python 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['flask run' or 'python run' which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276353/flask-run-or-python-run-which-to-use)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276353/flask-run-or-python-run-which-to-use does not answer my question about failure to open the serial port.  I've clarified the OP.