# Avoiding reading the entire config file in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a config file in Flask and it is loaded it by `app.config.from_object('app.config.Development')`. I expected only the Development class is read but it seems that `app.config.from_object` reads all classes in the config file in my investigation. Is there any way to read only a specific config class? I read this post and what I've said seems correct. [How to import from config file in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122312/how-to-import-from-config-file-in-flask)

```
class Development(Common):
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_ssm_params(
        '/dev/AccessKey',
        '/dev/SecretAccessKey')


class Staging(Common):
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_ssm_params(
        '/stg/AccessKey',
        '/stg/SecretAccessKey')


class Production(Common):
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_ssm_params(
        '/prd/AccessKey',
        '/prd/SecretAccessKey')
```

I have a config like this and have different AWS users for each environment. That means that I encountered an AccessDeniedException while the user `development` is reading the Staging and the Production class as the user `development` doesn't have permission to get `/stg/AccessKey`.

Comment: use a try/except?  ... really you should just use the ~/.aws/credentials file (maybe with different profiles... for testing or something) but really it should just live on the server and define its credentials as [default]

Answer (score 0):

Your application should not behave differently on different stages, if at all possible (as all hard rules, there are exceptions if need be). So ideally, you would only have one class and structure your settings so that they are independent of the stage - e.g. drop the dev/stg/prd prefix.