# Unable to load .flaskenv into Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile

I'm trying to containerize my flask application using Docker. The env variables which include client secrets, db creds, etc. are stored in `.flaskenv`. The application runs fine when run from terminal. But, when I build the application using Docker and do `docker run`, the env variables are not loaded and the API requests fail. I have tried using [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122312/how-to-import-from-config-file-in-flask) methods to achieve the same, for example, using a `config.py` file which contains the `class Config`. I import that class into flask entrypoint file and load into `flask app` using `app.config.from_object(config.Config)`  which seems to work fine on local but, fails when run using docker with `KeyError: "CLIENT_ID"`, which is an env variable in the application.

Note: My application ***does not*** use `docker-compose` and I am looking for a solution without using the same.

Please mention if any further details are required. Thanks in advance!

Dockerfile -

```
FROM <python3.9 image source>

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV FLASK_APP development

RUN apt-get update \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY pip /pip

ARG PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/pip/pip.conf
RUN python3.9 -m ensurepip
RUN python3.9 -m pip install --no-cache-dir <project-package>==0.1.0 \
    && useradd -U app_user --home /app \
    && rm -rf /pip

WORKDIR /app
USER app_user:app_user
COPY --chown=app_user:app_user docker/entrypoint.sh .
COPY --chown=app_user:app_user docker/start.sh .
RUN chmod +x *.sh

# ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "./start.sh" ]
```

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Added Dockerfile

Comment: You’re not copying the ‘.flaskenv’ file, are you ?

Comment: shouldn't it get copied when I'm building the project, like other files in the project??

Comment: let me try copying it explicitly and check

Comment: and that worked? What did you change? Shall I add this suggestion as an answer for the next one to find it?

Comment: no it did not. apparently the issue wasn't with docker but with poetry which I have been using to build the package. poetry doesn't modularize the env files. so i had to change it to config.py from .flaskenv